# Install multiple different files with the same name with WIX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX installer which needs to install files to two directories. In one directory we need to install a 32-bit version of the file, and in another, the 64-bit version.

However, the files have the same filename, which seems to cause WiX to merge them together and just store a single copy in the MSI.

Basically, I want the a directory structure similar to the following:

```
c:\Program Files\FooApp\MyLib.dll
c:\Program Files (x86)\BarApp\MyLib.dll
```

with the respective 32- and 64-bit versions of *MyLib.dll*.

The two files are currently in our .wxs file as separate *File* elements with separate ID's and stored as separate components. However, when I run the installer, it installs the 64-bit version of the file to both locations, and if I extract the contents of the MSI with [Dark.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Tools), it also shows both components have the same Source attribute.

Is there a way to convince WiX to store both files independently and ensure they're each installed to the right directory?

Comment: Can you add the components that describe both these files to your question?

Comment: The Id of each File element just needs to be unique (and of course the Source :) )

Comment: It's not WiX you need to convince. It's Windows Installer.

Comment: @PeterRitchie that's what I thought too, but the File elements *do* have different Id and Source attributes. It still ends up installing the same file to both.

Answer (score 0):

While WiX does have a concept called "smart cabbing" that is done based on checksums.

The behavior you are seeing is due to a different reason:

Windows Installer doesn't support 32-bit and 64-bit components in a single installer.   MSI databases are platform specific and the Windows Installer will work against you by "helping" you fix that *C:\Program Files* reference to point to the 32-bit location it thinks you be deploying to as a 32-bit MSI file.

The "correct" solution is to create a 32-bit MSI file and a 64-bit MSI file and bundle them together using a bootstrapper such as WiX [Burn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Tools).

If you really don't want the complexity of an EXE bootstrapper and only have one file to deploy to the 64-bit program files folder, there is a subversive hack.  I have observed in years past that MSI isn't smart enough to figure out that *C:\Progra~1* is in fact *C:\Program Files* and therefore it won't try to help you.

This little subversive hack has been useful when I need to deploy a file to both the 32-bit and 64 [MSBuild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) directory.

No promises on whether it'll work in the future... it's not documented by Microsoft.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure? With WIX I can build a 64-bit installer and mark individual components as 32-bit, and that works just fine. The problem only occurs when both contain files with identical names.